# How to save the database query before get the result at codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I use those function to get the database result.
I want to save all "select", "where"... etc query and load this for other function to use

```
$this->select('title, content, date');
$this->db->where('name', $name);
// Save the query here...

// Do other query
$this->db->select('name');
$query = $this->db->get('other_table');

// Load the query from the save point here
$query2 = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

Comment: what's your problem now?..i don't understand your question?

Comment: do you want to save the result ? or what ?

Comment: I want to save the query

Comment: $this->db->last_query()? (I can't imagine a scenario in which saving and recycling a query would be a good idea or good practice.)